# Remover dados de uma div com JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso remover as informações que estão dentro de uma  ou remover a div da minha web page com JQuery, tentei utilizar o código:

```
    $("#myid").html("");
```

e também

```
    $("#myid").remove();
```

nenhuma das soluções funcionaram, tem alguma outra maneira?

Comment: Podes mostrar o HTML que tens e queres remover?

Comment: Pode chamar o $("#myid").empty(). O empty() remove todo conteúdo que estiver dentro mantendo o próprio elemento.

Comment: Deu certo utilizando o método $("#myid").empty().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue alguns exemplos de como remover uma `div` ou remover o conteúdo da mesma:

1º Remover a `div` ao clicar em botão utilizando o método `remove()`:

```js
$("#removerDiv").click(function(){
    $('#divteste').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="divteste" style="border:1px solid">
 <p>Conteúdo da DIV a ser removida</p>
</div>

<br>
<button id="removerDiv" type="button">Remover DIV</button>
```

2º Remover o conteúdo da `div` mantendo a mesma ao clicar em botão com o método `html("")`:

```js
$("#removerConteudo").click(function(){
 $('#divteste').html("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="divteste" style="border:1px solid">
 <p>Conteúdo da DIV</p>
</div>
<br>
<button id="removerConteudo" type="button">Remover Conteúdo</button>
```

3º Remover o conteúdo da `div` mantendo a mesma ao clicar em botão com o método `empty()`:

```js
$("#removerConteudo").click(function(){
 $('#divteste').empty();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="divteste" style="border:1px solid">
 <p>Conteúdo da DIV</p>
</div>
<br>
<button id="removerConteudo" type="button">Remover Conteúdo</button>
```

Nos três exemplos acima, chamei a função para remover a `div` ou remover o conteúdo da mesma através do `id` da `div`. Em `jQuery`, para chamar um elemento pelo `id` do mesmo utiliza-se a sintaxe `#idDoElemento`.

Acredito que o seu código não funcionou porque você esqueceu de importar  a biblioteca `jQuery` dentro da tag `head` da página:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```